# Running a process as SYSTEM account

Tags: windows, elevation

I need to run a process with the SYSTEM account.

Starting from Administrator, which is the best way to elevate to the SYSTEM account?

It should work for Windows XP and later.

Comment: I need to be able to start/stop a service which runs in the SYSTEM account.

Comment: And to anticipate any question, no, I'm NOT absolutely trying to develop any kind of virus/malware/spyware etc. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to start or stop a service that is running in the system account, you don't need to run a process in the system account.

Instead, you need to set the ACL on your service (it *is* your service, right?) to grant interactive users the right to start or stop your service.

If it is *not* your service, then you ***really*** shouldn't do that.  If the author of the service decided that interactive users weren't supposed to start or stop their service, they probably had a good reason for making that decision.